# Received values from my SQL query are displayed incorrect in my Listbox

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, select

I'm trying to get values out of my database into my Listbox, I currently send all my results into a new object called Results

I want my listbox to show something like this:
Title(1)(enter)
Url(1)(enter)
Title(2)(enter)
Url(2)(enter)
and so on

---

It currently still gives an error at `OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();` but I have no idea why.

This is the exact code

```
     OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\martijn\Dropbox\Proftaak Periode 2 Identity\Database11.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";
        connection.Open();


        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = connection;
        cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT ZoekcriteriaID from Zoekcriteria WHERE ZoekCriteria = '" + Convert.ToString(lbzoektermen.SelectedItem) + "';";
        OleDbDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        if(reader1.Read())
        {
            resultaatid = Convert.ToInt32(reader1["ZoekcriteriaID"]);
        }



        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Titel, Webadress from Resultaat WHERE ZoekriteriaID = '"+ resultaatid +"';";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        lbresultaten.Items.Clear();
        List<Results> resultaten = new List<Results>();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            Results result = new Results();
            result.url = Convert.ToString(reader["Webadress"]);
            result.titel = Convert.ToString(reader["Webadress"]);

            resultaten.Add(result);
        }

        foreach(Results result in resultaten )
        {
            lbresultaten.Items.Add(result.titel);
            lbresultaten.Items.Add(result.url);
        }
```

I hope someone could help me,

Kind Regards,
Martijn

Comment: What kind of errors? Also add a try catch.

Comment: If _ZoekriteriaID_  is an integer field then you don't need single quotes around the value used in your where clause. However, you should learn as soon as possible to use parameterized queries

Comment: result.titel = Convert.ToString(reader["Webadress"]); maybe ... reader["Titel"] ??

Comment: The error is : Values for some ore more parameters are missing

Comment: And yeah I corrected that Mate, Thanks I didnt see that. but it crashes before it gets to that.

Comment: Great!  check if(reader1.Read()) .... else? resultaatid  is null? and then ? fails...

Comment: Found the issue in my query it says WHERE zoekRiteriaID when it needs to be zoekCriteriaID. Im so sorry for bothering with my mistake. it actually works now :) Thanks alot

Comment: You posted the same question yesterday as well. Not sure why duplicating?

Comment: This wasnt the same question, This had some different errors. sorry if it annoyed you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably lays in your where clause:

```
SELECT ZoekcriteriaID from Zoekcriteria WHERE **ZoekCriteria**
```

It should be a column name, not a table name.